# Missing a solution with Solve

Tags: equation-solving

The equation
$$\sqrt[3]{4-x^2}+\sqrt{x^2-3}=1$$
has a solution $x=\pm2\sqrt{3}$ but

```
Solve[(4 - x^2)^(1/3) + Sqrt[x^2 - 3] == 1, Reals]
```

only returns $x=\pm2$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{3}$. Why is that?

Comment: Long story short: Use [`CubeRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CubeRoot.html) instead of `^(1/3)`.